# Mysql update statement taking too long

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update

I have a Mysql update statement and it's running too long - 52 sec

```
update table_ea ea, table_a a 
  set ea.match_creator='S', a.match_state=N 
  where 
    ea.source_id=a.asset_id and 
    ea.source_name='S' and 
    ea.match_creator='S'  and  
    ea.entity_id like 'S'
```

Question:

a) Can we do an explain on this update statement in Mysql as we do for Select statements ?
b) Any suggestions on how to minimize the update time..

Comment: Consider reforming your question (title) in terms of an actual question like "What are the best practices for optimizing the speed of updates in MySQL?". Give more detail, what is the schema for the table? How many rows are in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how the corresponding select statement is performing. You are probably missing an index.

You'll need to post the table information if you want us to check.

Try posting `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_ea` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_a`

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ea.match_creator, a.match_state 
FROM table_ea ea, table_a a 
WHERE ea.source_id=a.asset_id 
AND ea.source_name='S' 
AND ea.match_creator='S' 
AND ea.entity_id like 'S'`
```

Comment: +1 Your answer is a bit better formed than mine was for basically the same thing. :)  My contention with the use of LIKE is that it often indicates some sort of user-supplied, application-generated search string and it _tends_ to have a negative impact on query performance, but you are right, it is not always the case.

Comment: | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                          | key           | key_len | ref              | rows    | Extra            |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | ea    | ALL  | FK_EKB_ENTITY_ASSET,IDX_SOURCE_ID_NAME | NULL          | NULL    | NULL             | 2647942 | Using w     here |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | EKB_ASSET_IDX,ekb_asset_on_asset_id    | EKB_ASSET_IDX | 386     | ekb.ea.source_id |       1 | Using w     here |

Comment: @user476554: thanks, but you could just update the question, that would make it more readable. Anyway, it looks like on your table ea, no index is used. Put an index on (source_name, match_creator and entity_id), see if the explain changes.

Comment: Also, as charstar mentioned, if you really update ea.match_creator='S' WHERE ea.match_creator='S', that is usually pointless - unless you replaced the real value by 'S' for the question, or the update has side-effects (like triggers)

Comment: I am not able to post the whole table creation statement:

Comment: `confidence_criteria` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2p_state` tinyint(3) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_EKB_ENTITY_ASSET` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SOURCE_ID_NAME` (`source_id`,`source_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
There is no index on (source_name, match_creator and entity_id)

Answer (score 0):

You should create indexes to the following fields of the tables in order to make it quicker (it accelerates the joins):

ea.source_id

a.asset_id

ea.source_name

ea.match_creator

ea.entity_id

I also recomend that you replace the like operator for entity_id with an equal operator, cause in this case it is the same.

Comment: I have the following indexes on table ea 1) entity_id 2) source_id & source_name and asset_id on a table. Now how do you want me to create an index ? you want me to create a single index on all columns in ea table (source_id, source_name, match_creator, entity_id) ?